# Increment MySQL column and get results

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is it possible to increment a MySQL column and get the results in a single query?  If so, how and is it more efficient than doing it in two queries?  Note that `version` is **not** an auto-increment column.

```
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE source_clients SET version=version+1 WHERE guid=?');
    $stmt->execute([$guid]);
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT version FROM source_clients WHERE guid=?');
    $stmt->execute([$guid]);
    $version=$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: No not possible you need to have two queries

Comment: There is no way to do it in one query. The way you're doing it is the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks Raymond and DaveyBoy.  Didn't know whether a sub-query could do so.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL does not have syntax `UPDATE ... RETURNING ...` or similar which exists in other DBs.

Comment: @JosMac that's why it has stored functions and procedures, which can do the same. In the end, syntactic sugar can always be mitigated.

Comment: @Mjh.  But wouldn't it still be multiple queries withing a stored procedure?

Comment: @user1032531 it would, but what is the goal you're after - performance or simplicity or both? Two queries in stored function would be executed within same transaction, that makes it as efficient as possible and no other RDBMS can make it more efficient from hardware POV. For you, programmer, that means you invoke one function instead of executing two. Personally, I don't prefer the magic that mixes inserts, updates, selects etc, but if you're after that magic - you can achieve it.

Comment: @Mjh  Agree, no magic!  For such a small benefit, I would not wish to implement a stored procedure.  Was hoping for a single query.  My last question was just out of curiosity.  I will stick with two queries.  Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @user1032531 what about an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html ? or INSERT ... SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Fred-ii-  How would either return the new incremented value?

Comment: @user1032531 well, you'd have no choice but to do a SELECT, so I guess we're back to square one. I take it that you want less code; are you wondering about performance?

Answer (score 0):

Just get yourself a good wrapper. It will mitigate the duplicated code, making your code effectively looks like as if it's just two queries in a single call.

```
$this->pdo->run('UPDATE source_clients SET version=version+1 WHERE guid=?',[$guid]);
$version=$this->pdo->run('SELECT version FROM source_clients WHERE guid=?',[$guid])
         ->fetchColumn();
```

The method above is from my [simple PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper)

But in fact, you could run these two queries in a single call with PDO.

If you turn emulation mode ON, it will be quite possible. Yet it won't make your code any shorter:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$sql = 'UPDATE source_clients SET version=version+1 WHERE guid=:guid;
        SELECT version FROM source_clients WHERE guid=:guid';
$stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['guid' => $guid]);
$stmt->nextRowset();
$version = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

I doubt this approach is worth the trouble.
More info you can find in the corresponding part of my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery)

Comment: Thanks YourCommonSense.  Off topic, but do you typically use such a wrapper for all/most of your queries?

Comment: Yes of course. There are no drawbacks and I hate to writhe the repeated code - so I am using this wrapper all the way if I have to work with raw PDO. Btw, I added an example for the literal answer to your question :)